# remove permissions _and_ digits after those permissions - from ls listing

Tags: ls, directory-listing

I am using my own generated 'script' to make recursive - yet - readable listings of my audio collection on HDD - I remove permissions from list, yet I remove 1st digit after permissions letters, and second - zero size digit right before date of folders.

Everything worked OK until I met something strange. First one is normal results I get from my 'script':

ls -lAFGgRN --time-style=long-iso %1 | grep -v ^total 
 | sed "s/drwxr-xr-x [0-9].* [0-9] //;s/-rw-r--r-- 1//;s/-rwxr-xr-x 1//;s/-r--r--r-- 1//" > ls-laR:

```
2011-09-13 11:39 A Tribute To Sepultura-1998-Sepultural Feast (Blackend, BLACK089CD (8 03341 16472 7), UK, Re-Release 2004)/

./A Tribute To Sepultura-1998-Sepultural Feast (Blackend, BLACK089CD (8 03341 16472 7), UK, Re-Release 2004):
    303768 2011-09-13 11:39 _log+cue+cover_.vol00+99.par2
  33621224 2011-09-13 14:07 _wav_.vol000+100.par2
  25106024 2011-09-13 14:07 _wv_.vol000+100.par2
      1806 2011-09-13 11:39 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.cue
      3702 2011-09-13 18:07 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.log
 496212410 2011-09-13 18:24 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.wv
    264054 2011-09-13 14:05 cover.jpg
```

But names of some folders - for the reasons I don't get yet - messing up:

```
(7 24388 91652 3), Netherlands, 2000)/
(8 8697-64763-2 8), USA, 2012)/
```

--- while ls -lAFGgoN --time-style=long-iso without using sed gives this listing:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1    0 2012-12-09 19:44 Chumbawamba-2000-Pass It Along (Single) (EMU Electrola GmbH, 7243 8 89165 2 3 (7 24388 91652 3), Netherlands, 2000)/
drwxr-xr-x 1    0 2012-08-25 00:26 Offspring-2012-Days Go By (Columbia, Sony Music, 88697 64763 2 (8 8697-64763-2 8), USA, 2012)/
```

So here is the question to Gurus:
What is happening, why my 'script' works OK with one folder(s) and fails for other(s)?

ps.'ls' and 'sed' are windows binaries, that is why I use "" for quotation instead of ''.

Comment: Your way is probably much harder than it needs to be. `ls` has _many_ formatting options. And there is also `find`, which is a more powerful way to traverse directory structures.

Comment: yes, I know about formatting options, but I still did not found "remove permissions letters w/ digits" :/ Anyway, can you post example of 'find' usage to get exact listing style I needed, please ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some hours of researching, and contacting with unix fellas, final version of my 'script' that works how I supposed to, is here:
ls.exe -lAFGgoRN --time-style=long-iso --group-directories-first %1 | grep -v ^total | sed "s/^d......... [0-9]//" | sed "s/^ *[0-9] //" | sed "s/^-......... [0-9]//" > ls-laR

And what's ls-laR contain:

```
.:
2011-09-13 11:39 A Tribute To Sepultura-1998-Sepultural Feast (Blackend, BLACK089CD (8 03341 16472 7), UK, Re-Release 2004)/
2012-12-09 19:44 Chumbawamba-2000-Pass It Along (Single) (EMU Electrola GmbH, 7243 8 89165 2 3 (7 24388 91652 3), Netherlands, 2000)/
2012-08-25 00:26 Offspring-2012-Days Go By (Columbia, Sony Music, 88697 64763 2 (8 8697-64763-2 8), USA, 2012)/

./A Tribute To Sepultura-1998-Sepultural Feast (Blackend, BLACK089CD (8 03341 16472 7), UK, Re-Release 2004):
    303768 2011-09-13 11:39 _log+cue+cover_.vol00+99.par2
  33621224 2011-09-13 14:07 _wav_.vol000+100.par2
  25106024 2011-09-13 14:07 _wv_.vol000+100.par2
      1806 2011-09-13 11:39 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.cue
      3702 2011-09-13 18:07 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.log
 496212410 2011-09-13 18:24 atributetosepultura98sepulturalfeast.wv
    264054 2011-09-13 14:05 cover.jpg

./Chumbawamba-2000-Pass It Along (Single) (EMU Electrola GmbH, 7243 8 89165 2 3 (7 24388 91652 3), Netherlands, 2000):
   238196 2012-12-09 19:43 _log+cue+cover_.vol00+81.par2
  9704324 2012-12-09 18:59 _wav_.vol000+200.par2
  6534724 2012-12-09 18:59 _wv_.vol000+200.par2
      588 2012-12-09 18:44 chumbawamba00passitalong-single.cue
     1816 2012-12-09 18:44 chumbawamba00passitalong-single.log
 61975146 2012-12-09 18:43 chumbawamba00passitalong-single.wv
    16956 2012-12-09 19:43 cover.jpg

./Offspring-2012-Days Go By (Columbia, Sony Music, 88697 64763 2 (8 8697-64763-2 8), USA, 2012):
    299028 2012-08-25 00:25 _log+cue+cover_.vol00+98.par2
  45669764 2012-08-25 15:51 _wav_.vol000+200.par2
  31920964 2012-08-25 15:52 _wv_.vol000+200.par2
    223828 2012-08-25 00:25 cover.jpg
      1671 2012-08-25 15:42 offspring12.cue
      2568 2012-08-25 15:49 offspring12.log
 315772732 2012-08-25 15:49 offspring12.wv
```

Thanks are going to all silent Gurus, whose spiritual inspirations were so much helpful to me ;)